# Difference between returning defer itself and returning defer.promise

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred

What's the difference between returning `def` and returning `def.promise()`

```
var def = $.Deferred();
// some code to set def

return def;
// or
return def.promise();
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/ - read the first 3 paras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deferred can be resolved or rejected by it’s caller. 
The promise intended to be given to any number of consumers and each will observe the resolution independently.

This concept doesn't allow changing of Deffered's state by consumers, and it's cool feature.

http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics